# Google Calendar API - max count of sync tokens

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have application where I used GSuite version of Google Calendar. And I have Android phones which watch changes. It means that each phone need x sync tokens where x is number of watched calendars. Is restricted number of sync tokens for one google account or for all accounts?

Comment: I think this is per google account, since a sync token is a piece of data exchanged between the server and the client. Also you can try testing it by using ["Try It" (Event List)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) and see if each user have different value for sync token. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for great help. I tried it. Tokens are bounded to resource (calendar) for two different Google Account was returned same sync token.

Comment: But I still dont know, how is here restriction (max. count of tokens for one calendar or for all calendars).